# Troubleshooting Typescript definition file for React Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm currently using React 16.4.1 and Typescript 2.9.2. I'm trying to utilise the reaptcha library:

https://github.com/sarneeh/reaptcha

Which I import like this:

```
import * as Reaptcha from 'reaptcha';
```

As there are no type definitions shipped, building currently gives me this (expected) error:

```
TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'reaptcha'. '...' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Despite this error, the code "works", but I've been trying for a long time to build just enough of a definition file to suppress the error. There seems to be a lot of different ways to do this based on how the library is export and I don't seem to have hit the right combination. For this definition:

```
declare module "reaptcha" {
  import * as React from "react";
  export default class Reaptcha extends React.Component<any, any> {
  }
}
```

Rather than solving the issue, this just presents a different error.

```
TS2604: JSX element type 'Reaptcha' does not have any construct or call signatures.
```

And this latter error, I'm quite stuck on. Any assistance getting past this appreciated.

The minimal case of where the component is used is:

```
  public render() {
    const Fragment = React.Fragment;
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Reaptcha
          ref={(e: any) => (this.captcha = e)}
          sitekey="MY KEY"
          onVerify={this.onVerify}
        />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
```

Comment: To understand why what you tried didn't work, I'd need to see the code that actually uses `Reaptcha` after importing it.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I've edited the question to include this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Reaptcha readme](https://github.com/sarneeh/reaptcha/#default---automatic-render) shows the import as:

```
import Reaptcha from 'reaptcha';
```

I tried this style of import with your original declaration and TypeScript was happy but the import didn't work at runtime.  When I enabled the `--esModuleInterop` TypeScript option, then everything worked.  Try using this option if you aren't already.

Comment: Moving to the `import * as...` seems to be the widely documented approach, such as in every React doc. Your alternate approach here totally fixes it, thanks a heap for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use:

```
declare module "reaptcha";
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. I'd really like to work in a direction for a more complete definition - I wrote types for all the props and functions but pulled them back to demonstrate this minimal case. I'll accept this is we don't get there though.